# Bitcoin Core Wallet - Google Authenticator?

Tags: bitcoin-core, two-factor-authentication

I know this is probably a weird question, but I need to be absolutely sure.

Does the Bitcoin Core wallet offer 2FA through Google Authenticator, kind of like Electrum does?
I'm asking because I've read that the people who update their GA app lose all their old codes, and I can't risk having that happen to me.

Is there anywhere in the Bitcoin Core client UI I can check if 2FA is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core does not have a 2FA functionality.